# How to reset all toolbars in OpenOffice or LibreOffice without affecting other settings?

Tags: openoffice, libreoffice, user-interface, reset, toolbar

How does one reset ***all*** toolbars in an OpenOffice or LibreOffice application to their default complement of displayed buttons in default positions without affecting (or resetting) other settings or customizations?

Comment: @fixer1234 Absolutely.  I made an edit... let me know if I satisfied your request.

Comment: @fixer1234 There is a UI to reset each toolbar, but there are many of them.  I think there is a file that can be deleted to reset all of them.

Comment: View - Toolbars - Reset?

Comment: @DavidPostill That menuitem seems to always be dimmed in LibreOffice, even when toolbars have been modified from their defaults.